# Convert JQuery Ajax code to plain JavaScript

Tags: python, django, ajax

This is Ajax code in my application, it adds object in Model without refreshing the page and shows no error:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#addbookform', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{% url 'books:home' %}",
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            price: $('#price').val(),
            num_of_pages: $('#num_of_pages').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"
        },
        success: function () {
            alert('Form submitted successfully!!');
        }
    })
})
```

I tried to convert it to JavaScript, however it add objects to model, but it refreshes the page and moreover it shows a 403 error in console and then fade away.

```
document.querySelector('#addbookform').onsubmit = savebook;

function savebook() {
    const name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
    const price = document.querySelector('#price').value;
    const num_of_pages = document.querySelector('#num_of_pages').value;

    const url = "{% url 'books:home' %}"
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            alert("Saved!");
        }
    }

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Can you please help me solve it?

Comment: Using javascript is a little tricky, django doesn't accept `POST` request without `CSRF token`

Comment: Yeah, how I can forget that, but even after adding it `csrf token` it is same issue